# Diagonally divs filling complete space of parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with relative height and width, in which are three boxes, being diagonally aligned and also fill the complete space of the relative parent div.

It's kinda tough for me to explain, so here's a picture on how I mean it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6gTQ.png
Besides the little space between the red lines all the space should be covered by the diagonal boxes.

Is that possible somehow? I'm very grateful for every advice or tip someone can shoot me!

Following code is what I got so far. The problem now where I'm stuck is how to make the diagonal divs fill out the complete space around them.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box-1">box1</div>
  <div class="box-2">box2</div>
  <div class="box-3">box3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-1 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: 33.33%; }

.box-2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: 33.33%; }

.box-3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%; }
```

Greetings, Toumazi!

Comment: The height of the divs will be relative to its content. If you want them bigger you can use `padding`, `height` or `min-height`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try that: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8jxn03od/)

```
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.parent > div {
    background: #c1c1c1;
}
.box-1 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: 33.33%; }

.box-2 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  height: 33.33%; }

.box-3 {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I'm now almost at how I want it. I changed your fiddle to following: https://jsfiddle.net/so0ts/aevvhk84/ (using skew instead of rotate, because it is closer to what I want). Now the only problem is that box1 doesn't fully cover the top part of the parent div and box3 doesn't for the bottom part, and both have still whitespace, box1 above and box3 below. Any idea how i could fix this/fill the space?

Comment: Well you could adjust the origin of the transition with `transform-origin`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aevvhk84/2/). Sorry if this if not what you want but my english is bad

Comment: Nice, thanks! That's also a good way to create the diagonal boxes. Might come in handy later :) No problem, mine is neither! I have a hard time explaining what I want to accomplish!